# blade foreach loops with missing values/indecies

Tags: php, laravel, loops, laravel-blade

I am currently hamstrung by a database scheme. I am not in a place to refactor (yet). I just need to get this going. To put it simply. I have a team. A team has a number of spots.. so a team can hold 1 user, can hold 12, or 1873 (unrealistic I know but you get the idea). Team also has a polymorphic relationship with positions. A position has a spot, user_id, and the id/model of the polymorphic relation. All of this is fine and dandy. A user is assigned a spot on a team.

In my blade file, I can do

```
@foreach($team->poisitions as $position)
  <p>{{$position->spot}}</p>
  <p>{{$position->user->name}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Then I will get a display (once formatted properly) of:

```
1 user1
2 user4
3 user10
7 user3
9 user12
```

Wonderful, this works as intended. However it's not what I need. I need to display however many spots are on the team, with blank spaces. So I need:

```
1 user1
2 user4
3 user10
4 ''
5 ''
6 ''
7 user3
8 ''
9 user12
10 ''
......
20 ''
```

I would love some help with this. I'll even take help to refactor this later, but for now, any help would be wonderful.

For completion sake, here's some code:

```
models\team.php

public function positions(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Position::class, 'positionable')->orderBy('spot', 'ASC');
    }


database/scheme teams:

    $table->text('name');
    $table->integer('spots')->default(6);


database/scheme positions:

    $table->integer('spot')->nullable();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete()->cascadeOnUpdate();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('positionable_id');
    $table->string('positionable_type');
```

Comment: how you decide spot should be empty.is there any condition or  $position->user->name return empty ?

Comment: If the spot is empty there will be no table row in positions. Only filled spots are stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like :

```
@php
$positions = collect($team->positions)->keyBy('spot');
@endphp
@for($i=0;$i <= $positions->keys()->last();$i++)
  @if (isset($positions[$i]))
      <p>{{$positions[$i]->spot}}</p>
      <p>{{$positions[$i]->user->name}}</p>
  @else
      <p>{{$i}}</p>
      <p>''</p>
  @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but not all the teams have users in a position, so adding the keyBy() gives a "relationship not found" error. Which again, makes sense, if there's no relationship there's nothing to key.

Comment: Never mind, I derped the implementation of your answer. It works as expected now. Thank you. I was pulling my hair out trying to figure this out.  Hopefully I'll get to refactor this soon.